# Is it possible to run the latest version of Akka Framework (2.5.2) in an Android project?

Tags: java, android, akka, kotlin, actor

I'm developing an Android project and wondering if it's possible to use `Akka` framework v. 2.5.2. This framework needs Java 8 to run and I know Android does not support Java 8. Is there a configuration that makes it work? Maybe using Kotlin?

Comment: did you manage to get Akka 2.5 working with Android ? or at least Akka 2.4 ?

Comment: I succedeed with the '2.3.16', because following versions are not compatible with Java < 8

Answer (score 1):

[Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) now supports **Java 8**, you can download the preview version [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html). With it you can use Java 8.

Comment: I think you missed the question a bit. The question isn't whether Android Studio supports Java 8. It's whether you can run Akka on Android given that it requires Java 8

Comment: He said "I know that Android does not support Java 8", which is not true anymore, so I told him. Given that his question may be redundant.

Comment: Not every version of Android supports Java 8 and we don't know his minimal required version. I think he wants to know whether he can use it on Android versions which don't support Java 8 (entirely)

Comment: I tried using Android Studio 3.0 but it gives me issues about dates. "Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter", because of Java 8

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible to run that version of Akka in Android. Most of Android developers use RxJava for concurrency programming in Android

Comment: I think I will downgrade Akka to make it compatible with Android and use RxJava for some aspects. Thanks.